# How to handle invalid input in java

Tags: java

I am making a simple Bank Deposit and Withdraw code. Code works for Deposit section but at the time of withdraw it asks withdraw values 2 times. And it takes last value for withdraw amount.

I think there I need to enter `scannerObject.nextLine();` somewhere, but where and how to use `scannerObject.nextLine();`?

Following is my sample code. There is one other class file BankAccount.java with only getter and setter methods.

```
package com.amit;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
        boolean option = true;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (option){
            System.out.println("Press 1 For Deposite. Press 2 For Withdrawal. Press 3 For Exit");
            boolean hasvalue = scanner.hasNextInt();
            if(hasvalue){
                //means user has entered integer value now check if its in 1, 2 if  its other
                // than this we'll take him out of program to print balance
                int userValEntered = scanner.nextInt();
                if (userValEntered == 1){
                    //code for deposite
                    System.out.println("Enter Amount To Deposite");
                    Scanner amountToDeposite = new Scanner(System.in);
                    account.setBalance(amountToDeposite.nextDouble());
                }else if (userValEntered == 2) {
                    //Code for withdrawal
                    System.out.println("Enter Amount To Withdraw");
                    Scanner amountToWithdraw = new Scanner(System.in);
                    if (amountToWithdraw.nextDouble() >= account.getBalance()){
                        System.out.println("Unable to Withdraw Given Amount, Try Other Amount");
                        continue;
                    }else {
                        double currentBalance = account.getBalance() - amountToWithdraw.nextDouble();
                        account.setBalance(currentBalance);
                        System.out.println("Thanks for Doing Business With us");
                    }
                }else{
                    //if user enters anything other than 1 or 2
                    break;
                }
            }else {
                //if user enters anything other than integer
                break;
            }

        }
        //code to print balance here.
        System.out.println("Your Balance is: "+account.getBalance());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `amountToWithdraw.nextDouble()` twice (once in the `if` condition, which is always executed, and once in the `else` branch). You should just call it once and save the result in a variable. Then use that variable in both places.

Comment: Debug your code, would know the reason, why getting called twice!

Comment: Try to use try catch block in your code, debugging always help to find bugs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @Tiij7, I found my bug that I was using `.nextDouble` twice. Now from now on, I'll make sure to save it in variable first, before using it. 
This is how I updated my code.

```
package com.amit;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
        boolean option = true;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (option){
            System.out.println("Press 1 For Deposite. Press 2 For Withdrawal. Press 3 For Exit");
            boolean hasvalue = scanner.hasNextInt();
            if(hasvalue){
                //means user has entered integer value now check if its in 1, 2 if  its other
                // than this we'll take him out of program to print balance
                int userValEntered = scanner.nextInt();
                if (userValEntered == 1){
                    //code for deposite
                    System.out.println("Enter Amount To Deposite");
                    Scanner amountToDeposite = new Scanner(System.in);
                    account.setBalance(amountToDeposite.nextDouble());
                }else if (userValEntered == 2) {
                    //Code for withdrawal
                    System.out.println("Enter Amount To Withdraw");
                    Scanner amountToWithdraw = new Scanner(System.in);
                    double withdrawAmt = amountToWithdraw.nextDouble();
                    if (withdrawAmt >= account.getBalance()){
                        System.out.println("Unable to Withdraw Given Amount, Try Other Amount");
                        continue;
                    }else {
                        double currentBalance = account.getBalance() - withdrawAmt;
                        account.setBalance(currentBalance);
                        System.out.println("Thanks for Doing Business With us");
                    }
                }else{
                    //if user enters anything other than 1 or 2
                    break;
                }

            }else {
                //if user enters anything other than integer
                break;
            }

        }
        //code to print balance here.
        System.out.println("Your Balance is: "+account.getBalance());
    }
}
```